# Apache LDAP Auth idle-timeout

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-auth-ldap

As part of the security policy we are upgrading out systems to comply with, I need to set our Apache LDAP Auth to have a idle-timeout of 15 minutes.

I.e. If the user stops using the system for over 15 minutes, the next time they go to use it they will need to re-authenticate.

Is this even possible?
If so, how can I achieve it?

My auth config in my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
AuthName "AD Authentication"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPUrl "URL"
AuthLDAPBindDN "DN"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "PASSWORD"
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative Off
require valid-user
```

Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that the connection to the LDAP server needs to time out, or the user's session needs to time out?

Comment: The users session - so if they idle for longer than 15 minutes, they need to re-authenticate.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, basic authentication is not session-aware in any way.  From the web server's perspective, they're actually forced to re-authenticate with every single request.

However, all browsers cache the credentials used for a basic auth connection, so that you don't need to re-enter credentials for every resource loaded from the server.  The issue that this creates in your situation is that there's no way to 'expire' that data from the client browser; it keeps it as long as it wants.

To implement session timeouts, you may be stuck moving away from basic auth and toward a session-aware application.

Comment: Mmm... that will get annoying. Is there any way to tell the browser to forget the credentials and to re-authenticate?

Comment: I don't believe so.

Answer (score 0):

A way to manually tell the browser to forget current credentials is to open the current address with another/invalid user.

```
http://testuser@www.mypage.com
```

Comment: This is not portable and might not work on all browsers. In fact there's no portable way to logout when basic or digest authentication is used.

Answer (score -1):

Try instructions from this site:
http://search.cpan.org/~ksolomko/Apache2-AuthCookieLDAP-1.14/lib/Apache2/AuthCookieLDAP.pm

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.